# Как создать уведомление?

Tags: java

Доброго всем дня!

Помогите, так как я новичок и изучаю java, передо мной стоит задача, которую я раньше не делала.

Я хочу сделать такую штучку, что-то вроде уведомления. В базе на таблице есть одно поле, которое должны заполнить люди, у которых роль - обычный пользователь. Но в то же время есть другая роль - типа проверяющий, все ли заполняют вовремя. Вот к этому человеку, когда он запускает приложение, должны приходить уведомления, мол, этот человек заполнил только что. Как сообщение, что ли, думаю, должен мигать, как при сообщении.

Что использовать, в какую сторону копать? Есть смутные предположения, что это делается с помощью сокетов, клиент-сервер, tcp и т.д. Или я ошибаюсь? Просто по этому в гугле все примеры приводят к чату, что не совсем подходит мне. Подскажите, что ли, было бы вообще классно с каким-нибудь примером, в общем, даже не знаю, как искать. Помогите, прошу. :)

Comment: @lp_4eva, для начала давайте определимся, что у вас за приложение. Веб? Десктоп? Android? Как происходит доступ к базе данных? Где она располагается?

Comment: База пока локально стоит, а приложение десктопное, обычный java se. Доступ к базе через jdbc.

Comment: Каким образом приложением будет пользоваться несколько человек, если база лежит локально? У каждого своя база или всё-таки база одна?

Comment: База одна, потом я надеюсь, что я поставлю базу на сервак.

Comment: Тогда что именно вызывает затруднения? Вы не можете составить запрос? Не можете отобразить сообщение? Не можете определить, кто запустил приложение - простой пользователь или проверяющий? Что-то ещё?

Comment: Да нет же, я не знаю, как сделать уведомление, когда база будет апдейтится. То есть когда другие люди заполнят базу, нужно чтобы приходило уведомление, что-то вроде мигающего всплывающего окна с текстом "пользователь 1 добавил это" и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для решения вашей задачи вам понадобится сервер. На сервере будет работать приложение-диспетчер, которое будет принимать сообщения об изменении базы от клиентских приложений, запущенных от имени простых пользователей, и отсылать уведомления приложениям, запущенным от имени проверяющих. Есть два варианта реализации такого сервера.

Первый вариант попроще, но приемлем только если вам не нужно мгновенно уведомлять проверяющих об изменениях в базе. В этом случае клиентские приложения, запущенные от имени простых пользователей, будут отправлять на сервер сообщения об изменении непосредственно в момент изменения, а запущенные от имени проверяющего будут раз в, скажем, минуту отправлять на сервер запрос на получение изменений за прошедший период. Этот вариант проще тем, что не нужно постоянно держать соединение между клиентом и сервером, регистрировать новых клиентов при запуске нового экземпляра приложения, отслеживать выход клиентов. Такой сервер может иметь вид веб-приложения, благо в Java более чем достаточно инструментов для их создания, даже без привлечения сторонних библиотек. Если такой вариант приемлем - читайте про сервлеты и реализуйте сервер на них.

Если же уведомления должны приходить мгновенно, то необходимо постоянно держать соединение между клиентскими приложениями и сервером. Здесь понадобятся сокеты, о которых вы можете прочитать в любой статье, посвящённой созданию чата на Java. Единственное отличие от чата в вашем случае будет тем, что обычные пользователи смогут только посылать данные, а проверяющие - только принимать.

Comment: Сервлет (если вы выберете первый вариант) не будет отправлять принятые сообщения. Он будет их записывать и отдавать проверяющему по запросу. Никаких jsp страниц не будет, сервлет будет писать ответ напрямую через `request.getWriter().print()`. Кстати, не обязательно использовать именно сервлеты, можно поднять на сервере веб-сервис на SOAP или использовать RPC (не рекомендуется из-за проблем с безопасностью).

Comment: @lp_4eva, про отправку post\get запросов, вот статья не плохая есть: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Comment: fori1ton, спасибо за ответ. Я тут попыталась сделать первый вариант, только столкнулась с проблемой одной. Допустим обычный юзер апдейтит базу и нажимает jbutton сохранить и срабатывает actionperformed. Дальше создается httpclient.
 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
Затем
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(); Тут между скобками как параметр должен передаваться что то вроде ссылки. Примерно я так делаю: localhost:8080//prjectname/ServletName?name="name"
Но что-то вообще не работает как response я получаю лишь страницу с ошибкой The requested resource is not available

Comment: @lp_4eva, а в браузере вы этот URL открыть можете? Может, стоит http:// в начале дописать? И два слеша после localhost:8080 - это вы здесь опечатались или в программе?.

Comment: @fori1ton, ой извиняюсь, это я сама написала, так как весь код не знаю как сюда поставить. В браузере тоже открыть не могу, тоже выходит ошибка 404. Там в общем выглядит так:

    "http://localhost:8080/test_servlet/myServlet?name=" + name");
 
Я создавала и делала как веб-проект и как обычное приложение. Когда делаю как обычный java проект, ошибка 404, когда делаю как веб приложение, если есть файл index.html, он его открывает при запуске, но как запускаю джава se файлы, все равно response приходит в виде ошибки 404.

Comment: Я смотрела отсюда http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13601435/how-to-call-the-servlet-from-java-swing-login-page-using-httpclient-in-apache

Comment: @lp_4eva, если вы не можете открыть этот URL в браузере, значит, веб-приложение не запустилось или запустилось с ошибками. Проверьте логи сервера и настройки вашего приложения.

Comment: @fori1ton, создала отдельную тему http://hashcode.ru/questions/407771/java-swing-servlet-connection, если Вам не трудно можете помочь?)